# Removing focus from subForm on a mainForm in Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a really frustrating problem. Basically I have a mainForm with 3-4 subForms all in datasheet view. What is a generic way to REMOVE focus from subForm after a record is selected and set it to a control on mainForm?

I tried:
OnCurrent Event:

```
Me.Parent.Form.SetFocus
Me.Parent.[Control].SetFocus
```

and it works half the time. The problem is, however, when user selects the record by clicking into some field in the subForm. Then the `highlighted`fields are either A) the field in the subForm, B) the field in the mainForm. Decided seemingly at random.

How do I CANCEL/REMOVE the focus from the subForm completely before setting the new focus elsewhere?

Comment: As you only select a record, you could disable all controls on the record - then they can't get focus.

Comment: If I disable ALL controls on the record, I cannot select the record by clicking on the disabled control. That means the only way to select the record is clicking the left corner of the record in datasheet view - very clunky. For now my workaround is more than sufficiant. It is simply irritating me that I had to make an extra work on trying to find a workaround in this case (and would like to find out the regular way to do this if such a problem arises).

Answer (score 0):

That would be to move focus to a control on the parent form:

```
Me.Parent!SomeControl.SetFocus
```

Comment: That should achieve the same result as `Me.Parent.[Control].SetFocus` or not? As I said, it is not the desired result.

Comment: You may have to move the call to another event.

Comment: The call is in correct Event, I solved it by a workaround of making my field look like a hyperlink and so when the user clicks the hyperlink it fires an `OnClick Event` which then sets the correct focus. The problem was (before making it look like hyperlink) that if used could click INSIDE the field, sometimes the mouse (focus) stayed in there (ie. it flickered to the correct place and then back). This was 50/50 chance pretty much as where the focus would stay.

Comment: There is no correct or incorrect event. Other options are OnEnter and GotFocus.

Comment: The problem is not the event itself. The problem is that the focus stays at 2 places at once (kinda). It stays in the `current record` in the subform and then goes to the `control` in the mainform. Problem is that it is decided (seemingly) at random which is the real focus in the end.

Comment: The focus is at one place only. If it doesn't move as expected, it is because something else interferes - typically the behaviour of the active control.

Comment: Is there any generic way to find out exactly what goes on (events order, requeries by master/child links changes etc) in the backround when something is pressed in a normal view form?

Comment: @emihir0 what about [RTFM](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/order-of-events-for-database-objects-e76fbbfe-6180-4a52-8787-ce86553682f9) ;) Notice that subform events occur before mainform events!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this peculiar problem that solved it for me in the end was to make the field in the subForm look like a hyperlink (ie. user can "click" on it).

Then make an `OnClick Event` which sets the correct focus, that is:

```
Public Sub [Field]_Click()
On Error GoTo Goto_Err

    'some other code
    Me.Parent.[Control].SetFocus

Goto_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Goto_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Goto_Exit
End Sub
```

This workaround is not ideal as the user has to click the field itself, rather than simply move to an another record by pressing up/down arrow.

Comment: It affects nothing. This is the working solution, or rather, the workaround which is not exactly ideal.